# Dynamic sort group in crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a sales report grouped by city and country. I need to change the order, some times the groups will be sorted by the total of sales and another times will be sorted by name (alphabetic). How can I do it? I'm using VS2013 C# and the tools of Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a formula with if else conditions and use the formula to create a group....

Best approach would be create a parameter and depending on the parameter selection write if else and use the formula in group expert

Comment: I can't see how this could work. I mean if I have 2 countries and inside of each one 3 cities. How can I sort the countries (and then the cities) by the total of its sales using a group name? I think that I can't use the summary fields on that point yet

Comment: Not summary fields use insert group that will change griups as per your selection

Comment: But I need summary fields to know the total of sales, thats the main problem

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it. I had my brain blocked, but you're right It works so fine!!!!